# You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-apps-script

I am creating a web app that has mulitple tabs. I want to have the google maps script in each tab, displaying the map etc.. Im getting the error: *You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.* When trying to use it like so:

In index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>West Chester Places</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="mapIcon.png">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAc0XJsW7RZN6i2BbKsEVBX5ONt2rKkQGY"></script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 20px">
<div class="tabContainer">
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button onclick="showPanel(0,'#7851a9')"><strong>Food</strong></button>
        <button onclick="showPanel(1,'#7851a9')"><strong>Bars/Nightlife</strong></button>
        <button onclick="showPanel(2,'#7851a9')"><strong>Other</strong></button>
        <button onclick="showPanel(3,'#7851a9')">Tab 4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tabPanel">

      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: auto; }
        body { height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #infobox { margin: 0px }
        #map-canvas { height: 460px }
      </style>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="mapapi.js"></script>

      <div class ="centerText">
            <center>
          <p>Come take a look at my favorite places in West Chester!</p>
            <p>Fun with Google Maps API <font size="3"><a href="https://github.com/rmcgarry3/FavWCPlaces" target="blank">(Source Code Here)</a></font></p>
            </center>
        </div>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>


    </div>

    <div class="tabPanel">
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: auto; }
        body { height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #infobox { margin: 0px }
        #map-canvas { height: 460px }
      </style>


      <script async defer type="text/javascript" src="mapapi.js"></script>

      <div class ="centerText">
          <center>
          <p>Come take a look at my favorite places in West Chester!</p>
          <p>Fun with Google Maps API <font size="3"><a href="https://github.com/rmcgarry3/FavWCPlaces" target="blank">(Source Code Here)</a></font></p>
          </center>
        </div>
          <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabPanel">
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: auto; }
        body { height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #infobox { margin: 0px }
        #map-canvas { height: 460px }
      </style>


      <script async defer type="text/javascript" src="mapapi.js"></script>

      <div class ="centerText">
          <center>
          <p>Come take a look at my favorite places in West Chester!</p>
          <p>Fun with Google Maps API <font size="3"><a href="https://github.com/rmcgarry3/FavWCPlaces" target="blank">(Source Code Here)</a></font></p>
          </center>
        </div>
          <div id="map-canvas"></div>


    </div>
    <div class="tabPanel">
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: auto; }
        body { height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #infobox { margin: 0px }
        #map-canvas { height: 460px }
      </style>


      <script async defer type="text/javascript" src="mapapi0.js"></script>

      <div class ="centerText">
          <center>
          <p>Come take a look at my favorite places in West Chester!</p>
          <p>Fun with Google Maps API <font size="3"><a href="https://github.com/rmcgarry3/FavWCPlaces" target="blank">(Source Code Here)</a></font></p>
          </center>
        </div>
          <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

In mapapi.js:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 39.9545904,
      lng: -75.6029956
    },
    zoom: 16
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  var bonBonInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="infobox">' +
      '<h1>Square One Bar</h1><h2>1400 S Michigan Ave</h2>' +
      '</div>'
  });

  var masInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="infobox">' +
      '<h1 class="title">My Home!</h1><h2>18th St & Michigan ave</h2>' +
      '</div>'
  });

  var loveAgainInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="infobox">' +
      '<h1 class="title">Dusek\'s Punch Bar</h1><h2>1227 W 18th Street</h2>' +
      '</div>'
  });

  var diaDoceInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div id="infobox">' +
      '<h1 class="title">Mercer 113</h1><h2>113 W Hubbard Street</h2>' +
      '</div>'
  });

  var bonBon = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 39.959006,
      lng: -75.607625
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'Bon Bon Sushi'
  });

  var mas = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 39.960265,
      lng: -75.603004
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'Más Mexicali Cantina'
  });

  var loveAgain = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 39.958445,
      lng: -75.605327
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'Love Again Local'
  });

  var diaDoce = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 39.958586,
      lng: -75.603630
    },
    map: map,
    title: 'Dia Doce Gourmet Cupcakes'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(bonBon, 'click', function() {
    GuidedTour();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(mas, 'click', function() {
    GuidedTour();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(loveAgain, 'click', function() {
    GuidedTour();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(diaDoce, 'click', function() {
    GuidedTour();
  });

  function GuidedTour() {
    diaDoceInfo.close(map, loveAgain);
    map.panTo(mas.getPosition());
    masInfo.open(map, mas);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(bonBon.getPosition());
      masInfo.close(map, mas);
      bonBonInfo.open(map, bonBon);
    }, 6000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(loveAgain.getPosition());
      bonBonInfo.close(map, bonBon);
      loveAgainInfo.open(map, loveAgain);
    }, 11000)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(diaDoce.getPosition());
      loveAgainInfo.close(map, loveAgain);
      diaDoceInfo.open(map, diaDoce);
    }, 16000)
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
...
```

In myScript.js:

```
var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tabContainer .buttonContainer button");
var tabPanels = document.querySelectorAll(".tabContainer  .tabPanel");

function showPanel(panelIndex, colorCode) {
  tabButtons.forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.backgroundColor = "";
    node.style.color = "";
  });
  tabButtons[panelIndex].style.backgroundColor = colorCode;
  tabButtons[panelIndex].style.color = "white";
  tabPanels.forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.display = "none";
  });
  tabPanels[panelIndex].style.display = "block";
  tabPanels[panelIndex].style.backgroundColor = colorCode;
}
showPanel(0, '#7851a9');
```

css.css:

```
.title{
    font-family: arial;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
.tabContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
.tabContainer .buttonContainer{
    height: 15%;
}
.tabContainer .buttonContainer button{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.tabContainer .buttonContainer button:hover{
    background-color: #d7d4d4;
}
.tabContainer .tabPanel{
    height: 85%;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 700px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: none;
}
.centerText {
  font-size: 5;
  font-family: arial;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

How do I use the same script/key for my multiple tabs?

Comment: why you have to add the google map api script more then once? do you have more than one google map api key?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  The code you posted only includes the script once, but can't tell what is in `mapapi.js`, is that _your_ javascript to load the map?  Or is what you posted one tab, where it is repeated for each tab?  If that is the case, include the map API in the common section of your page.

Comment: @geocodezip that's one tab out of 4. the ```mapapi.js``` will be different for each tab(i.e., mapapi2.js, mapapi3.js..). I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @asdru if you're talking about ```mapapi.js```, then yes, each tab will have a different script like: Tab1: ```mapapi.js1```, Tab2: ```mapapi2,js```, etc..

Comment: You are including the API for each tab.  Only include it once (either in the first tab or outside of the tabs in a common area of your code).  You still haven't provided a [mcve] that will demonstrate your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip When I add the API key to a common area of code and remove it from the tabs, the error goes away but it only works on the first tab.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue now.  **In the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site.

Comment: @geocodezip I have provided a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code on the contents of  `mapapi.js` because it isn't complete.  It would have been more helpful if you could have provided a StackOverflow code snippet that demonstrated the issue and didn't need to be fixed before being debugged.  When I click on the buttons I get a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.  The `tabPanel` array only has one entry.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cde70qvw/)

Comment: @geocodezip I added all of the  code. I apologize, I did not think Stack Overflow would let me post so much code.

Comment: All the code is unlikely to be a [mcve].  Perhaps you can take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cde70qvw/), and add the minimal necessary code to reproduce your issue (assuming the javascript error isn't what is causing the issue).

Comment: Also, you aren't allowed to have multiple `<div  id="map-canvas">`, the id **must** be unique.

Comment: making the map canvases unique doesnt solve it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are including two different versions of the same script. Instead of:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mapapi.js"></script>
```

You want to choose one of those lines. I'm guessing the first one if you are making more than one API call.

Comment: If I remove the first line, the error goes away but I get no map on a second tab. If i remove the second line, I get the error and no map.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by making a new `map` variable in another mapapi file:`mapapi0.js` which I called `map0`. Then I needed to change `#map-canvas { height: 460px }`and `<div id="map-canvas"></div>` to a map canvas with a new id in `index.html`.